# Hudson, is it possible to make a plugin configuration non-visible depending on job type?

Tags: hudson

With the plugin (SCM plugin) I'm working on the problem is that it doesn't work in any other job/project type than Freestyle-project. I'd like to hide the plugin configuration from project configuration page on other job/project types (maven, matrix etc), because it seems to distract people. I wonder if there's a "right" way of doing this, or any way at all?

Currently the project type is checked in checkout-method as a first thing, and if it doesn't match, the build is failed instantly, but this is not completely satisfactory solution, since it causes a bit more work to the end user.

**Edit**: I have a hunch that this could be possible by making some magic in descriptor associated to SCM class, but I'm still a bit short.

**Edit #2**: managed to solve this, I have been a bit drowsy it seems. Big Thanks for everyone who bothered their minds even a bit on this one.

Comment: File a bug report with Hudson.  ...... or Do you actually want to create a fix for that plugin? In that case file a bug report and start a discussion with the developers on how to solve it.

Comment: I guess I was a bit unclear. This is not yet a published plugin, just something in the works currently, and it's not meant to work with any other job type than just one. Sorry if I was unclear on my first post.

Comment: Haju, I don't believe so. --Hudson

Comment: believe that I was or was not unclear, or that there would be answer to my question? :) Unfortunately I'm very good at being unclear so I wouldn't take on that one, and fortunately there was an answer that fulfilled my needs. Hopefully useful to someone else too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this one. In SCMDescriptor there's this isApplicable method, that can be used to filter out the project types where plugin configuration is either shown ot not shown, like this:

```
@Override
    public boolean isApplicable(AbstractProject project)
    {
        if(!(project instanceof FreeStyleProject))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

so this solved my problem.